# Are there any Firefox themes that work when Ubuntu has a dark theme?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, themes

Does anyone know of firefox themes which are usuable when gnome has a black theme? I find that none of the borders are visible, and that often times text for certain context menues are completely ruined when I use even the standard theme (which one would think to be tested on a dark theme).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install [Sylish for firefox](http://userstyles.org/stylish/) and then, head to this [Howto on Firefox 3 and dark themes](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=873486). You can find the whole howto AND the rest of the steps on the second link. **If** that fails, just do a search on the FIRST link for 'gtk'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm, this certainly helps what is rendered inside the browser, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a great dark theme for Firefox called Dust. It was actually designed to match the Ubuntu Dust theme, so if you use both, integration is flawless.

You can try out either/both here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Incoming/DustTheme

Comment: Yes I definetly need a theme that works. Some of the theme, (even the default) just look so wrong if my theme is pure black.