# Change color of URL in dropdown menu of Firefox's address bar

Tags: firefox, themes

I am using a GTK theme with some dark elements, which causes problems in some applications. One of them is Firefox: the URLs in the drop-down menu of the address bar are dark blue on a  black background, as in the picture:

[image]

How can I change this color, or the background color, without changing my GTK theme? I remember that once was possible to do with the `userChrome.css` file, but I can't find it again.

I am using Firefox 14.0.1 under Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/113505/118798), installing [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/stylish/) and the [Firefox fix for Shiki-Colors](http://userstyles.org/styles/10822/firefox-fix-for-shiki-colors-gtk-linux-theme) the problem is solved without needing to tinker with `.css` files.

[image: how looks like now]

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this without installing add-ons is to modify userChrome.css.

If userChrome.css doesn't already exist in your profile/chrome/ folder (or if the chrome folder doesn't exist either) you have to create it:

```
<profile>/chrome/userChrome.css
```

Then add something like:

```
.autocomplete-richlistbox {
        background: #808080 !important;
        color: #000000 !important;
}
```

And restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still has this problem, here's my style for Stylish to fix the blue links in Numix theme.

http://sprunge.us/gNcU

Here's how it looks like now:

[image: Firefox Numix fix]

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Firefox 48 the next simple [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) script fixes colors of URLs and action texts in the popup list of the urlbar and color of "Show All Downloads" button:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul)
{
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-url-text,
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-separator-text,
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-action-text,
  #downloadsHistory {
    color: #2998ff !important;
  }
}
```

where you can change the color to another.

Additional lines for URLs in RSS preview:

```
#feedHandler a {
  color: #2998ff !important;
}
```