# Change color of links in dropdown menu of Firefox's address bar

Tags: firefox, colors, css

Basically I am having the same problem as 
[Change color of URL in dropdown menu of Firefox's address bar](https://superuser.com/questions/457072/change-color-of-url-in-dropdown-menu-of-firefoxs-address-bar)

However, the "fix" accepted by the author in that thread involves changing the background color of the drop down list, whereas I would like to change the color of the links themselves.

Anyone know how to do this using userChrome or which CSS handles have to be set to get a change in color?

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of just the links:

```
.ac-url-text {

    color: #00AA00 !important;
}
```

Note: if you also want to affect "actions", like 'switch to tab', you can use `ac-action-text` for that.